# Use Object Arguments in Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

Is this possible?

```
function testObj(testArg) {
    //Do obj stuff here
}

testObj.prototype.addFn = function() {
    this.test = testArg;
}
```

This will not work because the original objects arguments are not available to prototype, but is there a way to access them without having to pass them in all over again through the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function testObj() {
    // take a copy of the arguments
    this._args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);

    // Do obj stuff here
}

testObj.prototype.addFn = function() {
    this.test = this._args[0];
}
```